# can I use both core data and firebase in my Xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, core-data

could I use core data for the login sign up part in the app but firebase for the editing of  profile page ? I am only a 6 day beginner of swift/Xcode so I am not sure and am sorry if it is a dumb question. I am not sure if using both respectively would be risky or would end up with a lot of errors?
I already have the login and signup working using coredata.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: why u want core data for login and sign up.? Use firebase authentication.

Comment: Firebase is a multi-user (shared data) online first cloud database with multi-user authentication. Generally speaking, CoreData is not. It's offline and more of a local database with cloud sync (CloudKit) for each users data and does not offer multi-user authentication. e.g. it's the wrong tool for an app where you need multiple users to access the same real-time event driven dataset. CloudKit does have a 'public database' for each user but its application would differ from Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

The simple direct answer is yes you can do that.
But that's not the correct way of doing it.

Since you are already plan on using Firebase, you should use firebase Authentication for signup and login also that would completely save you the trouble of using core data specifically for login.

So means the better way is using firebase to handle auth as well as user profile/editing